# can class attributes in python can be written in protected?

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, attributes, python-3.6

can **class attributes** in python can be written in protected

```
class A:
   list_nums = [1,2,3] 

A.list_nums.append(4)
```

How can we restrict `list_nums` from being accessed

Answer (score -2):

We can protect the class attributes by using get and set classmethods.

```
class MyClass:
    _var = 10
    @classmethod
    def get_value(cls):
        return cls._var
    @classmethod
    def set_value(cls,value):
        return
```